# SymPy: Evaluate given expression with given variables

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy expression involving two variables `a`, `b`. I would now like to evaluate this expression for specific values of `a` and `b`. Using a `lambda` like

```
import sympy


def get_expression(a, b):
    # Complex function with a simple result. I have no control here.
    return a*b + 2

a = sympy.Symbol('a')
b = sympy.Symbol('b')
z = get_expression(a, b)

f = lambda a, b: z
print(f(1, 1))
```

only gives

```
a*b + 2
```

though.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that [lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) is what I need:

```
f = sympy.lambdify([a, b], z)
print(f(1, 1))
```